# コメントもなくクローズされ、クローズされた理由がわかりません

Tags: 討議

先日、私が回答をした質問があります。

[node-jsの常時実行](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48185/)

私には質問に問題があるとは感じられずに回答し、既に承認済みのマークが付いているにもかかわらず、コメントもなく「質問の範囲が広すぎる」としてクローズされました。クローズされた理由が全くわかりません。どうしてこの質問が「質問の範囲が広すぎる」クローズされたのでしょうか？また、承認済みのマークがあれば、質問者が「質問内容を絞り込んだり詳細な要件を追記する」必要はないはずです。このような質問を「質問の範囲が広すぎる」としてクローズすることは適当なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

該当の質問を見てきましたが、私も問題があるようには感じられませんでした。

まず、承認済みなのにクローズするのか？は棚上げして、
該当の質問がクローズされるべきかどうかを考えてみます。

---

> ＞`node.js`を使ってtwitterのbotを作成し、cmd.exeでforeverコマンドを使って実行させています。
>   ＞無料サーバーを借りて実行させたりしたいのですが、どうすればよいかが全くわかりません。

既にローカルに環境があると言うことから、`node.js`の環境を構築できる技能があることが分かります。
ですので、
「無料サーバで`node.js`の環境を構築しようと四苦八苦しているが動作しない」か、
「`node.js`が動作する無料サーバはあるかわからない」か、
「そもそも、無料サーバの選定の仕方が分からない」のいずれかだと思います。

ただ、ここでいくつか考えられるので、「本当に質問者が知りたいことが分からない。」
"質問内容がハッキリしない"という理由でクローズされるのであれば分かります。
ですが、"質問の範囲が広すぎる"という理由でのクローズには疑問を抱きます。

また、クローズ後にコメントがないという点でフォローアップが無いのも問題です。
クローズするだけではなく、「どうすれば、良い質問としてオープンできるか？」というところまで考えるべきだと思います。

---

次に、承認済みになった後、クローズする必要があるかどうかです。
SOは単なるQ&Aサイトではなく後から疑問を持った人が回答を得るために集合知的なモデルを確立していると考えています。
ここで考えるべきは、質問が解決した後、その質問が後から疑問を持った人が探しやすく回答がわかりやすいか否かだと思います。
より良いコンテンツを残すために承認された後も質問は修正され分かりやすくなるべきだと思いますし、
改善のしようがなく、質問を残したとしても誰にも理解されないであろう質問はクローズされるべきだと思います。

ここで該当の質問が承認済み後クローズされるべきかどうかですが、
回答とやりとりにより、質問者の疑問点が明らかになっており、
且つ、無料サーバで`node.js`を使うにはどうすれば良いか？という後続の人の足がかりになるという点で、
特にクローズするべきではなく、質問を編集することで解決する内容だと思いました。

Answer (score 3):

（長文失礼します。）
**クローズとなった原因についての私の推察**
[node.js](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js)について完璧に知識がない私からすれば、おぼろげな範囲さえわかりませんでした。そこで、[Node js 入門](https://www.slideshare.net/SatoshiTakami/intoroduction-nodejs)をさらりと眺めてみました。
私のサーバープログラミングの知識は、[java](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)サーブレットの入門書を読んだ程度です。

質問の核は、自前で作ったサーバーサイドのコードをクライアント側の自分のパソコンで動かしても、電源切ればおしまいだ。だから、そのコードを実行するサーバー環境を無料で構築して、サーバー側で常に動くようにしたいのだけれども、**どうすればいいのか全くわからない。**
そのため、その**方法論**を尋ねているのだと読めました。Myakuさんのおっしゃる通り、詳しい方だと、また分岐した解答が頭に登るのだろうと思いますが、いずれにせよ、ここがきっかけだろうという事は読めます。

そこで、質問の範囲が広いと判断されてしまったのだろうと思いました。

しかし、Yasuhiro Nijiさんには、広いとは思えなかったという事で、**主観のずれ**が起きてしまったのでしょう。

コミュニティのメンバーは個人個人の人間で、やはり評価は常にそれぞれ主観的なのだと思います。

しかし、**主観的な面だった**、という事は、クローズ票を投じた方5名の方達こそが、（ある程度推測はできるものの）自身の見解をYasuhiro Nijiさんに伝えるしかないのだろうと思います。それしかYasuhiroさんの疑問に答えた、と正確には言えないでしょう。

したがって、Yasuhiro Nijiさんからすれば、究極的には、私Haruが答える話ではないという事になるかと思いますが、思ったところを書いてみました。

更に推察をすれば、単に知識のあるなしによるもの。
あるいは、私が推察したように考えた人がおられたのかもしれないということ。([node.js](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js)についての理解の質量はさておいて。)がきっかけなのではないかなと思っています。

**クローズ票の票はどこまで客観的か？**

上に続いた理由として、他には、本当にあくまでも推察なのですが、クローズ票に誰かが一票でも入れた場合、おおざっぱに言って、つられて投票する人も、0ではないと思います。これが、2票や3票入っている状態だと、その流れも強まるようです。そう思う理由は下に書きました。5票とはいえ、1票入れば2票入る流れが強まり、4票入れれば5票目は決まったようなもの、という事もあり得ますね。これはスタックオーバーフローの方たちに問題があるのではなく、投票という仕組みにそういう誘惑がひそんでいるものだと考えています。

これはたまにスタックオーバーフローの方たちが、流れで投票される現象に、一定の悩みを示している過去の投稿やコメントから推察しています。本当にそういう気持ちで投票されているのかどうかは、その投票者個人に確かめなくてはならないため、証拠は全くありませんが、そう推察できる例は、過去にあります。

これは若干の心理の絡みがあると思います。まず**質問を見て、それから判断する**のではなく、まず**票が入っているのを**見て、じゃあその質問には何か問題があるのかをより鋭く見ようとしてしまう。
5票は単独の1票が5票になっているように見えて、全く中身は違います。票数はあくまでも結果であって、何票入っているのかは、その票を入れた個人の主観を表せるものではないと考えています。そうした主観に影響を与える効果を最も強く発揮するのは**最初の一票**なのだと思います。

クローズ票を遊びや出来心で投じる人がいるとは考えにくいです。それなりの理由を持っていなければ投じません。(という信頼感が、このコミュニティにはあると思っています。)ですから、コミュニティのメンバーの投票である事が、一定の信頼性を持っているがために、逆にその一票にそのような力を与えてしまうのだろうと考えます。私はコミュニティのメンバーが、出来るだけ制度に即して、コミュニティ全体の利益のために、投票制度を利用しようと努力していると信じています。ですが、その努力と功績が、却って最初の一票に強い力を与えている、という悩みがあると考えています。

いずれにせよ、結果的に、当該提起された質問の中には今回は確かにあいまいだと言える部分があることは否めないかなと思えます。
（少なくとも、あらを探せばないとは言えません。）

結論を言えば、客観的な部分というのは、それだけの票数が入っているという数字だけを言うのだと思います。何票入っているのかは誰にでもわかりますからね。しかし、どのような思いでその票が入れられたのかという過程は、全て主観によるものだと考えます。

ですから今回のケースに便乗して主張することがあるとすれば、投票状態を見るのではなくて、質問それ自体を見て判断してください。という事になるでしょうか。もし最初からそうしてるというのであればスルーしていただければいいです。推察に推察を重ねて文章を組み立てていますから、今回の件は関係ないかもしれないんですけど。

**承認された後にも拘わらず質問がクローズされてしまったこと。**
承認されたという事は、「質問者が満足のいく回答があったことを認めた」と、「みなされる行為があった」ということです。（納得してないけど承認ボタンを押す人もいるからです。）
今回Yasuhiro Nijiさんにとってわかる質問でも、他の人にはわからない質問であるかもしれません。Myakuさんがおっしゃってらっしゃるように、質問を分岐する事ができるようだからです。そのため、回答があり、かつ、それに対応する承認がある事は、質問のわかりやすさを示す尺度ではないという事になります。見たところ私もたくさんの回答をYasuhiroさんから頂いて、プログラミングやプリフェラルな環境に詳しい方だなとお見受けしております。だから、今回はYasuhiroさんと、あるいはほかの何名かの方にはわかる質問だったという事なのだと思います。もしくは可能性のある選択肢は全て網羅できるという自信をおもちだったのかもしれません。確かに２つの意味に取れる質問も、2つとも答える意志が回答者にあれば、さほど問題にはなりませんからね。

**さらにコメントもなくクローズされたこと**
クローズされた質問にはたいていコメントを載せるものですから、載せられていない今回は、あまりないケースかもしれません。

私は今まで下記のような状況を見た事があります。

・今回のように、回答に承認が附き、その後クローズされた場合。
・逆に、クローズされた後に、回答が入り、その後承認された場合。
・回答がつき、承認される前にクローズされた時。

このいずれの場合も、質問が改善されない限り、クローズが解除されることはないようです。（忘れられている場合も多いと思います。）この3つは自慢じゃありませんが、私が体験者です。もちろん質問者として。

つまり、質問内容それ自体が基準となっているようで、回答や承認がついているかどうかは関係が無いという事になります。

回答と承認があり、そしてコメントもなくクローズされたというケースは、確率的に見てもなかなかない事だと思います。比較的珍しい例なので、Yasuhiroさんの活動期間を考慮すれば、このような疑問をお持ちになるのもわかります。私も、質問者のために、上記で書いた部分をもう少し詳しくしてほしいというコメントなりを書いてから、しばらく時間をおいて、クローズするべきだろうというところ、あるいは、クローズ後に、すぐにコメントを示すべきところは、Yasuhiroさんと同じであり、このような質問が出る事は、全くおかしい事ではないと考えます。以上です。

**まとめ**
・クローズの原因は、やはりあいまいなところは探せばあったという事。範囲が広いか、趣旨が明確ではないかはどちらも取ろうと思えば取れると思います。
・投票という制度自体に、流れを産む誘惑的な仕掛けがあります。
（コミュニティが悪いと言っているのではなく、投票という仕組み自体にです。）
却ってコミュニティのメンバーに対する信頼性が、最初の一票の価値を大きくしているように見えます。
・回答と承認がある事ではなく、クローズはやはり質問内容を基準としてなされるようです。
・クローズをすれば、コメントを残した方がいいという事は私も同意見です。（早急に問題の特定が出来、質問者さんも質問を改善することが出来ます。）

Answer (score 2):

私は再オープン票のカウントのルールを理解していないのですが、この質問に関しては一度リセットされている気がします。再オープンに賛成の方は、もう一度再オープンに投票してみて票が反映されているか確認した方がよいかも知れません。

また、再オープンに反対の方々には、理由を説明していただきたいと思います。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/20268